# Node.js error Error: Cannot find module 'datejs'

Tags: node.js, datejs

When datejs is installed using npm and when a script (below) is executed, the following error is obtained:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'datejs'
at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:11)
at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
at require (module.js:368:17)
```

datejs module exists under correct node_modules.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code which line  you are getting this error?

Comment: And the package.json file also

Answer (score 0):

Try `require('./node_modules/datejs/index.js');`